# Run ALL junit integration tests before reporting failures

Tags: java, testing, junit

Currently i am writing integration test for a several ecommerce shops via a Junit.

What I want to do is execute all test cases despite any failures occurring during, then report all failures at the end.

Are there any frameworks, testCaseRunners e.t.c i can leverage to achieve this or will I have to manually achieve this via code i.e swapping junit assertions for simple equality checks whilst logging failures in a collection of some sort.

Hope my question is understood but I can extend my question further if clarification is needed.

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221891/continuing-test-execution-in-junit4-even-when-one-of-the-asserts-fails?

Comment: This link might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038547/how-can-i-have-the-ant-junit-task-run-all-tests-and-then-stop-the-rest-of-the-bu.

Comment: Thanks Priyesh. Your first reply was just what i needed.